# How to get dotted pairs in Lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I've searched google and other places for a while but I can't find out how to generate or create dotted pairs. I ask this because, I need to turn a list that looks like this:

```
(X Y Z)
```

To a list that is in this format:

```
((X . 1) (Y . 2) (Z . 3))
```

Where the numbers represent the index. I have a function that turns the list into the format of

```
(X 1 Y 2 Z 3)
```

Here is that function:

```
  (defun listFormat (l)
     (defun place-index (idx l)
        (if (null l)
          nil
          (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                  (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l)))))
     (place-index 1 l))
```

But I'm not sure how to get dotted pairs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code has a very basic mistake:

```
(defun listFormat (l)
     (defun place-index (idx l)    ; <<<---- This DEFUN is wrong
        (if (null l)
          nil
          (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                  (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l)))))
     (place-index 1 l))
```

Don't nest DEFUN. That's just **wrong**. DEFUN defines a global function. Whenever you run listFormat, it redefines the **GLOBAL** function PLACE-INDEX. You may have seen similarly nested functions in SCHEME using DEFINE. In Common Lisp you should not use DEFUN for a nested local function.

In Lisp local functions are defined with FLET or LABELS (for recursive functions).

```
(defun listFormat (l)
   (labels ((place-index (idx l)
              (if (null l)
                  nil
                  (append (list (first l)) (list idx)
                          (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l))))))
       (place-index 1 l)))
```

Also Stackoverflow is the wrong place to solve your homework. Google searches is also the wrong way to learn Lisp programming.

I propose to use the good old way of reading an introductory book and using a reference.

Here is a basic **introductory Lisp book** for download: [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/).

**Reference sheets**: a small [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~zanoni/mc336/2008-2s/lisp/CommonLisp/quick-reference.pdf) (PDF) and a more detailed [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://clqr.berlios.de/).

*Dotted pairs* are called *conses* in Lisp.

See the real online reference for Common Lisp, the [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/14_.htm).

Answer (score 6):

You want the else-branch to read:

```
(cons (cons (first l) idx) (place-index (+ idx 1) (rest l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

And by the way, for the question itself, this code will do:

```
(defun listFormat (lst)
  (loop for idx from 1
        for item in lst
        collect (cons item idx)))
```